# How can I use RESTful services with Django + Mongoengine?

Tags: django, rest, mongoengine

I want to use my django web application with RESTful services.

I already created my models, using mongoengine. Let's say I have 2 models:

```
class Shop(Document):
name =  StringField()
description = StringField()
address = StringField()
image_path = StringField()

class Item(Document):
name =  StringField()
description = StringField()
shop = ReferenceField(Shop)
images = ListField(StringField())
```

In this scenario, I want that shop has list of items. And when I make a request to REST url for the shop, the shop and the item list should be serialized into JSON and response is sent to client.

How can I do that? Which REST framework is suitable for that case?

Should I keep items in the shop class?(e.g items=(ListField(ReferenceField(Item))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Piston in Django with custom model classes built using MongoEngine.

This worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I think using generic views would be the easiest way, afaik there is no REST / Mongoengine framework available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out tastypie-mongo engine?
It's a Django application that provides MongoEngine support for Tastypie.

http://django-tastypie-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#simple-example